# Linking Walker Customized Category List Through Buttons

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on customizing `wp_list_categories` function to list all categories from `<li>` tag list into list of buttons, I managed to list the names of the categories into the buttons, but still need to link them with the categories pages. I tried to add `$item->url` in the `location.href` but it is not working.

Here my code in the **function.php**:

```
class Walker_Simple_Custom extends Walker_Category {  

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth=1, $args=array()) {  
        $output .= "\n<ul class=\"buttons_cats\">\n";  
    }  

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=array()) {  
        $output .= "</ul>\n";  
    }  

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {  


        $output .= "<button onclick=\"location.href=''\" type=\"button\" id=\"css3button\" class=\"item\">".esc_attr( $item->name );
    }  

    function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth=0, $args=array()) {  
        $output .= "</button>\n";  
    }  
}
```

and this is the call of the customize function:

```
<?php

  $args = array(
    'show_option_all'    => '',
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'ASC',
    'style'              => 'list',
    'show_count'         => 0,
    'hide_empty'         => 1,
    'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
    'child_of'           => 0,
    'feed'               => '',
    'feed_type'          => '',
    'feed_image'         => '',
    'exclude'            => '',
    'exclude_tree'       => '',
    'include'            => '',
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'title_li'           => __( '' ),
    'show_option_none'   => __('No categories'),
    'number'             => null,
    'echo'               => 1,
    'depth'              => 1,
    'current_category'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'         => 0,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'walker'             => new Walker_Simple_Custom
); 

wp_list_categories($args);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !

use `get_category_link` function and pass it with `$item->term_id` and this should direct you to the clicked category page.

```
$output .= "<button onclick=\"location.href='". get_category_link( $item->term_id ) . "'\" type=\"button\" id=\"css3button\" class=\"item\">".esc_attr( $item->name );
```